# Confusion when running multiple MySQL instances

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up multiple MySQL database instances on a single server and I'm getting some very weird results.  I can get the different instances up and running, listening on different ports, using different .cnf files, using different datadirs, etc.  As far as I can tell, I've got two separate, independent instances.  Below is a copy of when I run "ps aux | grep mysql".

```
root      2827  0.0  0.0   2592  1140 pts/1    T    14:30   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf
mysql     2858  0.0  1.0 119692 18312 pts/1    Sl   14:30   0:00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-external-locking --port=3306 --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
root      2887  0.0  0.0   2592  1140 pts/1    T    14:34   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my2.cnf
mysql     2921  0.0  1.0 119492 17596 pts/1    Sl   14:34   0:00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my2.cnf --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2 --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid --skip-external-locking --port=3307 --socket=/var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock
```

Now is where it gets weird.  When I log into the db's remotely with Navicat, I can edit the contents of the databases, no problem.  However, when I run a script to access the data on the different dbs, I get a a table doesn't exist error because the script is trying to access the first instance running on port 3306, even though I specify port 3307 for my second connection resource.

Another thing I noticed is that if I SSH into the server housing the two DB instances and log in to one of them using `mysql -u root --port=3306 -p` and do something like change the password for the root user, the root password has changed when I try to connect using `mysql -u root --port=3307 -p`;

I've been working on this for a few days now and I'm completely stumped.  I'm working with Fedora 8 on an Amazon AWS server.  Any help would be most appreciated!

Here's the contents of my.cnf:

```
[mysqld] datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
port=3306
user=mysql
old_passwords=1
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

And here's the contents of my2.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql2
socket=/var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock
port=3307
user=mysql
old_passwords=1
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld2.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid
```

Comment: You need to post the contents of `/etc/my.cnf` and `/etc/my2.cnf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to the mysql server running on port 3307, use:

```
$ mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock
```

`--port` just changes the TCP/IP port number, but when you connect via socket you need to give it the other socket name.

Comment: Awesome!  That fixed it and got everything working like expected.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you run mysql and don't explicitly specify a hostname other than localhost (I suggest using the IP address of the local machine: 127.0.0.1), all MySQL commands (including mysql itself) will assume a socket connection. Your --port parameter was effectively ignored, and the mysql client was connecting via /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, which if the first instance's socket.

Check this out:

```
$ mysql --host=localhost --port=3306
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Versus:

```
$ mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```